# execute all the list of statement in a txt file one after the other in powershell

Tags: powershell

execute.txt- has list of executions statements on each line as below..

```
Get-Content "C:\execute.txt" | foreach { "Intofile_1" + $_ }| Set-Content "C:\execute_file1.txt"

Get-Content "C:\execute.txt" | foreach { "Intofile_2" + $_ }| Set-Content "C:\execute_file2.txt"
```

I would like to call the execute.txt file and execute all the commands/statements in one attempt.

Can you please help on how to achieve on powershell

Comment: The commands above are in `execute.txt` (instead of execute.ps1) and shall read the file they are in? Sorry but that's nonsense - please clearify.

Comment: Rename your file to `execute.ps1`.

Answer (score 7):

`Get-Content` only ever *reads* the specified (text) file, it never *executes* anything; in order **to execute the statements contained in `C:\execute.txt`** you have **two choices**:

- *Either*: **Rename `C:\execute.txt` to `C:\execute.ps1`**, as [Ansgar Wiechers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630171/ansgar-wiechers) suggests, and invoke the renamed file (directly or with `&`, unless you need "dot-sourcing" (see background information below)):

  ```
  & "C:\execute.ps1" | ... # Note the *.ps1 extension
  ```
- *Or*: If, for some reason, you cannot rename your file, you can **combine `Get-Content` with `Invoke-Expression`** to achieve execution:

  ```
  # PSv3+:
  # -Raw reads the entire file into a single string
  & { Invoke-Expression (Get-Content -Raw C:\execute.txt) } | ...

  # PSv2:
  # -Raw is not available, so the array of lines returned by Get-Content must
  # be joined with newlines ("`n"`) to form a single string first.
  & { Invoke-Expression ((Get-Content C:\execute.txt) -join "`n") } | ...
  ```

  - Note the use of `& { ... }` around the `Invoke-Expression` call, which ensures that statements execute in a *child* scope, which is necessary, because `Invoke-Expression` invariably executes statements in the *calling* scope; if you truly need "dot-sourcing", omit this wrapper.

---

**Background information**:

- Windows PowerShell by design does not directly execute statements stored in a `*.txt` file.
- In fact, **the *only* filename extension PowerShell recognizes as containing a PowerShell *script* (a series of executable statements) is `*.ps1`**
- **Script files are invoked in two fundamental ways** (in all cases it is optional to specify the `.ps1` extension when referring to the script file):

  - In a ***child* scope** (the typical case):

    - Via **`&`, the call operator**, which can always be used, but is *required* if the script file name/path is ***single- or double-quoted* or specified via a *variable***:

      - e.g., `& './my script.ps1'` or `& $script`
    - ***Directly***, for file names/paths that are specified as ***literals* without single- or double-quoting**:

      - e.g., `./myscript.ps1`
  - In the ***calling* (current) scope**, using the **"dot-sourcing" operator, `.`**:

    - e.g., `. ./myscript.ps1` - note the need for a space between `.` and the script path
  - As for the **difference in scoping**:

    - Executing in a *child* scope (operator `&` / direct execution) means that variables, functions, and aliases defined in the script are local to the script execution and go out of scope when the script ends, without affecting the calling scope.
      This is typically what you want: have a script perform its task without side effects on the caller's state.
    - Executing in the *calling* scope (operator `.`) means that variables, functions and aliases defined in the script become part of that scope and remain even after script execution ends.
      This is typically used to add functions and aliases to the calling scope for *later use*, and is the same mechanism that is - implicitly - used to add custom functions and aliases to an interactive session via the user's profile file, `$PROFILE`.
    - The difference between `.` and `&` only mattters when invoking *PowerShell scripts*; you can use either operator to execute an *external program* or *open a document*, in which case they both behave the same.

---

Comment: With the detailed information provided here, this is the answer that should be Accepted; it is one of the best explanations I have seen anywhere, including being better than some pro Powershell books.

Answer (score 0):

Ansgar Wiechers has the right answer; rename `execute.txt-` to `execute.ps1`, and then just call that file. <s>If you really insist on keeping the name,</s> Alternatively, after renaming, you can 'dot-source' the file: `. "execute.ps1"` or call it explicitly: `& "execute.ps1"`. See [SS64 on dot-sourcing](https://ss64.com/ps/source.html) and also on [calling](https://ss64.com/ps/call.html); while they do similar things, there *are* important differences.

Comment: Both dot-sourcing and using the call operator will open the file with the associated program. If there is no program associated with that file type Windows will prompt the user to select one.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - Then I must have a weirdly-misconfigured system, somehow, because dotting or calling does work for me - and if I `start` the file (e.g. `start execute.txt`), it opens up with the associated program.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin: I'm curious how you achieved that configuration (they run in the same console window?); however, it's safe to say that this is _not_ the default behavior and should therefore neither be recommended nor relied upon. Ansgar's description of the expected behavior sounds correct.

Comment: @mklement0 - If I knew how I got there, I wouldn't consider it 'weirdly misconfigured'. :) I've since confirmed Ansgar's statement on a system that I know is 'out of the box', with no externally imposed (domain) policies or anything like that.